# Default caller value for AS3 method

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way of setting the default value of a method scope parameter to be the caller?

In AS3 you can set default values for method parameters like so:

```
function myFuntion(param1:String="hello",param2:int=3) {
```

And you can pass a reference to an object by saying:

```
//method of Class1
function myFuntion(obj:Object) { } //do something with obj

//in Class2
var class1:Class1 = new Class1();
class1.myFunction(this);
```

So the question, is there a keyword that can be used like:

```
//method of Class1
function myFuntion(obj:Object = CALLER) { } //do something with obj

//in Class2
var class1:Class1 = new Class1();
class1.myFunction();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only default function parameter value that is accepted for the type Object is 'null'.

```
function myFunction(obj:Object = null):void {};

var class1:Class1 = new Class1();
class1.myFunction();
```

Comment: Yeah, a bit more reading in the docs arguments.callee docs seems to say as much.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to what you ask, and that is a good thing for encapsulation and code readability. You should be forced to deliberately pass **this** so that it is clear to anyone reading Class2.as what your function is being given references to.

In general, you should ask yourself "why?" anytime you have a function parameter of type **Object** (that's pretty general!). I'm not saying there is never a good reason for it--for error reporting purposes, for example--but all too often it's the sign of poor OOP design (e.g. using an Object because you're too lazy to make a proper data structure class for what you're passing, or to circumvent typechecking)